Rust - The Trait Bound `diesel::expression::select_by::SelectBy<User, Pg>
let user_result = users
 .filter(username.eq(&login_data.username))
 .select((id, username, password_hash, created_at)) 
 .first::<User>(&mut conn);

I take this error ;
the trait bound (Integer, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamp>): load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<User, _> is not satisfied
this is a mismatch between what your query returns and what your type expects the query to return
the fields in your struct need to match the fields returned by your query in count, order and type
consider using #[derive(Selectable)] or #[derive(QueryableByName)] + #[diesel(check_for_backend(_))]
on your struct User and in your query .select(User::as_select()) to get a better error message
the following other types implement trait load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<U, DB>
this is my user struct :
#[derive( Selectable, Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct User {
  pub id: i32,
  pub username: String,
  pub password_hash: String,
  pub created_at: Option<NaiveDateTime>, // Nullable field
}

and also schema.rs :
diesel::table! {
users (id) {
    id -> Int4,
    username -> Varchar,
    password_hash -> Varchar,
    created_at -> Nullable<Timestamp>,
 }
}

how can i fix that

Please [edit] the title of your question to be descriptive, unambiguous, and specific to what you are asking. For more guidance, see How do I write a good title?.

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

Please use #[diesel(check_for_backend(_))] as the compiler suggests.

My guess is you may not have enabled the feature flag to support NaiveDateTime for Timestamp.

Actually I did. Here is my toml file ;
[dependencies]
actix-web = "4.0"
actix-cors = "0.6"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
dotenv = "0.15"
diesel = { version = "2.0", features = ["postgres", "r2d2","chrono"] }
r2d2 = "0.8"
bcrypt = "0.12.0"
chrono = { version = "0.4", features = ["serde", "std"] }

Sorry, I solved the problem. I added #[diesel(table_name = users)] to the User struct and the incompatibility was gone. Thank you all of you.
